# Using FLASH with ASP.NET - YAY or NAY?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, flash, flashdevelop

I know i can use AJAX and SILVERLIGHT with my ASP.NET web page. But what do you think about using flash with asp.net? Can this be done? How can this be done? Would you recommend me using flash at all with ASP.NET? I will NOT be using WEB SERVICES, just a plain ASP.NET website.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** What about performance issues???

Comment: If you arent using web services ( or web methods ), it really should make no difference, as one is a client side technology and the other is server side.  Unless you need to communicate between the two ( data exchange, authentication, etc... ) it really doesn't matter.  You can easily server Flash content from an ASP.net server if that is your question.

Comment: Performance will be no different to any other client side technology

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used Flash in ASP.NET websites plenty.

Software should always boil down to the best tool for the job, if Flash is the way you need to go for your RIA, then so be it.

Remember, ASP.NET is nothing "new/different" ultimately, it is just a fancy HTML generator.

Therefore, to use flash, you simply use the plain old HTML [OBJECT and EMBED tags](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) to place the Flash on the page.

The benefit of using things like ASP.NET (or any other framework) is that you can encapsulate the EMBED logic to use things like [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Answer (score 2):

flash is client side, what you use server side has very little impact on it.

Answer (score 1):

Given Flash's high market penetration (98%+), I think Flash is a great way to go regardless of the underlying platform.

But, as with everything, it depends on what you want to do.  If you want to deliver a rich user interface via Flash, you should consider using Flex.

There are several tools to help integrate a Flash/Flex application with ASP.NET. One of these that I recommend is [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html).

Comment: We've used WebOrb as well - pretty decent software IMHO

Answer (score 0):

It certainly can be done! We've done entire flash-based websites in the past that rely on data generated by a CMS and read from flash via XML. There are of course lots of gotchas (loading html text, multilingual characters), but once you've done it a few times you'll get the hang of it.

Flex is probably a better option.